# How to handle when user authorizes in asp .net core

Tags: oauth, authorization, azure-mobile-services

I am usin google or facebook authentication for my azure mobile app. Is there a way to process authorized users ? I want to handle authorization to create and save a new users in my database.

Comment: If possible, please add what you have done.

Comment: I created a new controller with endpoint decorated by AuthorizeAttribute. I am calling this after successfull authentication and i can process his info there. Not very elegant solution but could not find anything else.